# Cannot share from iOS to GooglePlus

Tags: ios7, google-plus

I'm working on social package in my app and I developed sharing using multiple social networks. While implementing Google+ SDK for iOS, I logged in and retrieved my account information, but when I start sharing, the application crashes

```
id<GPPNativeShareBuilder> shareBuilder = [[GPPShare sharedInstance] nativeShareDialog];
[shareBuilder setPrefillText:obj_featured.title];
UIImage *image = [self captureScreenShot];
[shareBuilder attachImage:image];
[shareBuilder open];
```

Simply, I commented and test every line, the problem is with the `-open` function.
The error appears for me when running over real device is:

```
 *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '*** -[__NSPlaceholderDictionary initWithObjects:forKeys:count:]: attempt to insert nil object from objects[1]'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x2e783fd3 0x38ffcccf 0x2e6c2463 0x2e6c222b 0x1e7cd5 0x1c014f 0x1e9f31 0x1ea21d 0x1ea429             0x1c07f3 0x201179 0x2f16cc73 0x2e74f25b 0x2e74e72b 0x2e74cf1f 0x2e6b7f0f 0x2e6b7cf3 0x33610663 0x3100316d 0x106131 0x39509ab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Maybe you have to convert your `UIImage` to `NSData` (purely a guess). Is your SDK the last one?

Comment: Were you able to solve this? I've the exact same problem.

Comment: anyone found any solution for above issue ?